# c# dynamic LINQ query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview, combobox

In my winform application, I am adding combobox column in datagridview and selecting the combobox item using the following code:

```
var entityModel= new AdminEntities();
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboIsNew = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
var isNew = (from a in entityModel.TOWERs select a.ISNEW).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
cboIsNew.Items.AddRange(isNew.ToArray());
int i = dgvLoadTable.Columns["ISNEW"].Index;
dgvLoadTable.Columns.Insert(i, dgvCol);
dgvLoadTable.Columns[i].HeaderText = dgvLoadTable.Columns[i + 1].HeaderText;
dgvLoadTable.Columns[i + 1].Visible = false;
```

Is there a way to do this by a simple function in which I will pass the tablename and column name/index only? Also, If I do this:

```
dgvLoadTable.Columns.Insert(i, new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn());
```

Then how do I add item to this dynamically created combobox? I tried to add items like the following, but it doesn't work:

```
 cboIsNew.Items.AddRange((from a in entityModel.TOWERs select a.ISNEW).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cboIsNew.Items.AddRange((from a in entityModel.TOWERs select a.ISNEW)
  .Distinct().Select( x => new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() ).ToList());
```

You would need to see the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with specific values using x as the source, but the way I've layed out should create a List of objects that should be able to be added.